# Wordpress get content of page (with php inside)

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I would like to be able to have the html content of a wordpress page. I try to use this kind of code :

```
$my_id = 5369;
$post_id_5369 = get_post($my_id);
$content = $post_id_5369->post_content;
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
$content = str_replace(']]>', ']]>', $content);
echo $content;
```

But it returns empty an empty string whereas when I access to the page, the content is not empty. Indeed, there is php code inside the content of the page I would like to get. So, how I can do to get the content of this page knowing that there is php code inside?

**data content :**

```
<div id="content" class="oe">
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array('post_type'=>'mcm')); ?>
<div id="slid" class="div-slider">
  <?php
    /* get value */
    $appercu_collection = get_post_custom_values ( "o" );
    if ($appercu_collection) { // si appercu
        class Image {
            public $link;
            public $image;
        }

        /* init value */
        $imageCollection = array ();

        /* complet collection */
        foreach ( $appercu_collection as $img ) {

            $img_tmp = new Image ();
            $img_tmp->image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $img , 'medium' )[0];
            array_push ( $imageCollection, $img_tmp );
        }

        display_slider ( $imageCollection );
    }
    ?>
</div>
<div id="content-meta">
    <div class="meta-detail-header"><?php echo get_post_custom_values ( "_at" )[0]; ?></div>
    <div class="meta-detail-title"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
    <div class="audio">
        <div id="audio-inner">
        <?php $au =  get_post_custom_values("_au");
            if ($au) {
                $urlguid = wp_get_attachment_url ( $au [0] );
                if ($urlguid) {
                    display_audio ( $urlguid );
                }
            }
        ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="ex">
    <?php 
        $newdebut = get_long_formatted_date( $date_debut[0] );
        $newfin = get_long_formatted_date( $date_fin[0] );
    ?>
    <div id="expo-temp-dates"><?php echo sprintf( __( 'From %s to %s' , 'wptouch-pro' ) , $newdebut , $newfin );?></div>
    <?php 
    $tar =  get_post_custom_values("_tarif"); 
    if($tar) { ?>
    <div id="exprice"><?php echo $tar[0]; ?></div>
    <?php }?>
</div>
<div id="content-o" >

    <!-- GET Content -->
    <div id="content-description" class="detail-container">
        <?php display_zoom_controls(); ?>
        <?php echo wpautop( wptouch_the_content() ); ?>
    </div>
    <!-- GET BONUS -->
    <div id="content-bottom-sticky">
        <a href="<?php echo $url_guide;?>"
            class="tappable-button tappable dark" role="Button"><?php _e( 'TUIDE' , 'wptouch-pro' ); ?></a>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<!-- inside intervalle -->
<?php endwhile; 
wp_reset_postdata();?>

<?php if( ! $content) { ?>

<div id="title" class="title">
    <h2><?php _e( 'N' , 'wptouch-pro' ); ?></h2>
</div>

<?php }?>
```

Comment: Are you trying to get contents of your own pages or someone else?

Comment: Did you connect to your database?

Comment: __"there is php code inside the content"__ share you content as well.

Comment: @Godinall : What do you mean by "did you connect to your database" \n

Comment: @jogesh_pi : Sorry, but I can't share my php code inside the content. It's confidiential.

Comment: @user2429082 for your above code to work you have to connect to your database first otherwise it makes no sense. We don't need to see your real content, Jogesh_pi was asking to to show the php code that generates your contents.

Comment: @jogesh_pi I took the content of my php inside my post

Comment: @user2429082 where you used `$loop = new WP_Query( array('post_type'=>'mcm'));`? where is while loop? where you applied `apply_filters('the_content', $content);`?

Comment: @jogesh_pi I forgot to add the while loop. I do : `apply_filters('the_content', $content);` in other php page not inside this page.

Comment: @Godinall I retry my code with a different page id, which didn't contains any php functions, only html, and it works. By the way, I was able to do a call to the function `mysql2date` so I don't think I'm not connect to the database.

Comment: It looks you are using a modified template, try echo apply_filters('the_content', get_post_field('post_content', $post_id)); and see what you get

Comment: @Godinall I try it, and the answer is empty. I try on the other page wich contains no php inside just html, it send me all the content.

Comment: @user2429082 okay, trying using echo $content=file_get_contents('YOUR-POST-URL'); and see what you get

Comment: I try and it's still empty. It's a page I think, not a post (maybe a difference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally resolve my problem by doing an ajax request to my page and get the content thanks to 
[wp_remote_get](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_remote_get) . Indeed, It was a page with a custom type post and custom fields.
Here is my code :

```
$resp = wp_remote_retrieve_body( wp_remote_get($url,$option));
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($resp);
$element = $doc->getElementById('content');
$content = $doc->saveHTML($element);
```

$content contains the html content of the element with the id "content" of the page whose url is $url.